# For loop with if(array[i + 1]) goes out of array bounds; how to loop to beginning?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array and a `for` loop an `if` statement that checks for `i + 1`. However, on the last iteration of the loop, the array goes out of bounds. I want to loop back to the beginning of the array when this happens. What is the best way to loop around back to `array[0]`? Here's my code:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
array[0] = new int(5);
array[1] = new int(7);
array[2] = new int(3);
array[3] = new int(1);
array[4] = new int(9);

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i + 1] != 0)
        // Do something (obviously in this example, this will always occur)
    {
}
```

I can do the following, but it requires me to duplicate my code (and my current code inside this is huge). Is there a better way to do the following?

```
int[] array = new int[5];
array[0] = new int(5);
array[1] = new int(7);
array[2] = new int(3);
array[3] = new int(1);
array[4] = new int(9);

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i != array.Length - 1)
    {
        if (array[i + 1] != 0)
            // Do something (obviously in this example, this will always occur)
        {
    }
    else
    {
        if (array[0] != 0)
            // Do something (obviously in this example, this will always occur)
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it check for `i+1`?

Comment: forget `for` loops. Use a `foreach`

Comment: `foreach` is not a good choice, if you have to compare the next element.

Comment: It checks for `i + 1` because in the actual code it subtracts `array[i]` from `array[i + 1]`. I didn't include that in the simplified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if ((i + 1 < array.Length && array[i + 1] != 0) || (i + 1 == array.Length && array[0] != 0))
        // Do something (obviously in this example, this will always occur)
    {
}
```

Comment: `&&` operator does not evaluate the right part if left is already `false`, because it requires both sides to be `true` to return `true`.

Answer (score 6):

Use modulus:

```
if(array[(i+1) % array.Length] != 0) {...}
```

This will basically subtract array.Length from (i+1) until (i+1) < array.Length

Answer (score 0):

```
array[(i + 1) % array.Length]
```

Should do the trick without too much pain.